# Neo4j batch-import

Tags: import, neo4j

i have nodes of the same type but with different properties - those properties come from a database and even nodes of the same type and "sub-type" can have different properties ...

looking at http://github.com/jexp/batch-import, how could i go about nodes that have dynamic properties ?

Asking this cause, as it is stated in the readme,

```
Property values not listed will not be set on the nodes or relationships.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it means is you leave the properties you don't want to set empty in the TSV file. Like so:

```
firstName  middleName  lastName
Christoff    HasNoMiddleName
ThisGuy  HasAMiddleName  AndALastName
```

will result in nodes like this:

```
Node[...]({firstName:"Christoff", lastName:"HasNoMiddleName"})
Node[...]({firstName:"ThisGuy", middleName:"HasAMiddleName", lastName:"AndALastName"})
```